# BX Slider and scrolling the page

Tags: mobile, touch, swipe, direction, bxslider

I am using bxslider for a mobile site, horizontally scrolling images. The problem is that page is not scrolling if you touch bxslider. How can I catch the finger direction and scroll the page down ? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the option touchEnabled to false.